# condition number after scaling matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Maybe a well-known question. Let $\Sigma$ represent a real symmetric positive definite matrix, i.e. a covariance matrix.

Which diagonal matrix $D$ with positive diagonal minimizes the condition number $\frac{\lambda_{\max}(D\Sigma D)}{\lambda_{\min}(D\Sigma D)}$?

In contrast to some other literature on preconditioners, the pre- and post multiply matrix $D$ are the same here. There could be a clue [here](http://www.nt.ntnu.no/users/skoge/vgprosessregulering/papers-pensum/ch3-ch10-2ndedition.pdf) if the pre- en post-D would be allowed to differ. Unfortunately, I have no access to eq. (A.74).

Numerical experiments suggest that the identity matrix is always optimal if $\Sigma$ is two dimensional. For larger dimensions, the optimum is nontrivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no simple relation (at least nowadays) for the optimal diagonal scaling which minimizes the spectral condition number of a matrix except for several special cases.

The classical result for SPD matrices is due to van der Sluis, which states that for an SPD matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$,
$$
\kappa_2(DAD)\leq n\min_{\text{$\tilde{D}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ diagonal}}\kappa_2(\tilde{D}A\tilde{D}),
$$
where $D=\mathrm{diag}(a_{11}^{-1/2},\ldots,a_{nn}^{-1/2})$.

There is, however, a [paper by Braatz and Morari from 1994](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/29534/1/BRAsiamjco94.pdf) where the authors propose a formulation of the optimal scaling problem leading to a convex optimization problem.

Comment: I have just looked into the paper you mentioned and I believe that they also consider scaling by $D_1 A D_2$, unfortunately.